# Replace items into mongo object via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to edit an item in my mongodb collection.

In my database, I have a "person" that has the following value:

```
{
"_id": {Random Object Id},
"property": [{
  "model": ["BMW", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  "color": ["red", "blue", "yellow"],
}, {
  "model": ["Test0", "Test1", "Test2"],
  "color": ["black", "blue", "brown"],
}]
}
```

Here the "property" is an Array and has 2 objects. Also all of them should be in order.
I want to change one of the value in the second object. The second object should be like

```
  "model": ["Test0", "Test1", "Test2"],
  "color": ["black", "red", "brown"],
```

How do I apply this kind of code in my express server and also how do I place the "red" color into the second element ?

```
personModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.session.person._id}, {$set: {
`property.$[index].color` : "red"}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the index you can just manually define it:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{_id: req.session.person._id},
{
  "$set": {
    "property.1.color.1": "red"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K0P1aA8xRds)

If you want to change a specific color you should use the update `arrayFilters` option, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{_id: req.session.person._id},
{
  "$set": {
    "property.1.color.$[elem]": "red"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      elem: "blue"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/do1j0Dt5d8x)

Comment: Okay this works. I'd commented another problem recently but I solved it so don't mind about it. Thank you very much.